# Searching Inside XML Files For String Of Text Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with some XML files,
Each xml file has a unique folder path that is written on it,
like this:

```
<FolderName>C:\abc</FolderName>
```

In addition to the other data written on the file.

Is there a way to search with PowerShell inside the XML files and find the file where the folder path I was looking for is there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `SelectNodes` something like below if you have multiple nodes.

for your first question You can directly call it

```
[xml]$myxml = @"
<FolderName>C:\abc</FolderName>
"@



$result = $myxml.FolderName
Write-Output $result
```

You can use below code if you have Multiple elements

```
$child = 'INT10'
[xml]$XmlDocument = @"
<TextValuess>
    <TextValues Name="Value1" Override="true" Type="String">
        <DEV>Source=DEV;Catalog=DEV_DMT;Integrated Security=SSPI;</DEV>
        <INT10>Source=LAB;Catalog=TST_INT10;Integrated Security=SSPI;</INT10>
        <INT>Source=LAB1;Catalog=TST_INT1;Integrated Security=SSPI;</INT>
        <INT2>Source=LAB10;Catalog=TST_INT12;Integrated Security=SSPI;</INT2>
    </TextValues>
    <TextValues Name="ENVIRONMENT" Override="true" Type="String">
        <DEV>DEV</DEV>
        <INT10>INT10</INT10>
        <INT>INT1</INT>
        <INT2>INT15</INT2>
    </TextValues>
</TextValuess>
"@

$result = $XmlDocument.SelectNodes("//TextValues/$child")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this to read each file in and print out the value but if the value is a number of subchild elements down then you'd use something like the second $xml sample. If FolderName isn't in a consistent place in the tree then it's going to be more complicated.

```
$apdir = "Y:\Neil\DSeries\XML\"

clear

foreach($apfile in Get-ChildItem $apdir)
{
      $xmlfile = $apdir + $apfile

      [xml]$xml = Get-Content $xmlfile

$xml.FolderName
$xml.one.two.three.four.FolderName
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all

I finally managed to build a script that works with chat gpt
This is what he suggested to me and it works :)

```
# Specify the folder path you are looking for
$targetFolderPath = "C:\abc"

# Get a list of all XML files in the specified folder
$xmlFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "Path\to\your\folder" -Filter "*.xml"

# Loop through each XML file and search for the target folder path
foreach ($file in $xmlFiles) {
    $content = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw
    if ($content -match ("<FolderName>$([regex]::Escape($targetFolderPath))</FolderName>")) {
        Write-Output "Folder path found in: $($file.FullName)"
        # You can also extract other data from the XML file if needed
    }
```